# Getting a 502 error when trying to 'Include' a view in php

Tags: php, view, include

I am currently trying to 'include' two views onto my homepage view.  One creates the comment and that works.  The second is to show the comments and that code is what throws the 502 error.

Here is the controller:

```
 /**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 * GET /comments
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function create()
{
    return View::make('comments.create');
}

public function display($comment)
{
    $comment_id = $this->commentRepository->find($comment);
    return View::make('comments.show')->with('comment', $comment_id);
}
```

Here is the dashboard view:

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('content')
<h1>Dashboard</h1>
@include('comments.create')
@include('comments.show')
@stop
```

Here is the 'show' view:

```
@foreach
<p>{{ $comment }}</p>
@endforeach
```

Comment: What error message exactly do you get?

Comment: This seems like a problem with your route configuration. Are you using a framework to assign requests to your functions?

Comment: Yes I am currently using Laravel.

Comment: Then make sure that your function is actually called as intended. Check your log file and make sure the templates are not causing any problems.

Comment: I don't see any issue with the templates.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you check your webserver/php-fpm logs for PHP error (/var/log/...) output if code seems to be correct.